# Where to save the value of TextEditingController in a form

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart, mobile

If I have an editable form "add and edit",
which is the best practice to save text from Text Fields Controllers? in view or in controller like bloc or provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best practice to keep UI related aspects together. So I would recommend storing the TextEditingController within a widget.

Most likely you would need a stateful widget.

Comment: But in this case on edit voew you have to set its value in ui and set other values from controller file !!!

Comment: You would need to share your code for me to help further.  Sounds like you might also be adjusting the value of the textfield from external to the widget. This can be achieve using state management. Most likely some kind of trigger where the controller tells the widget to rebuild the textfield.